# How to write a "OR WHERE YEAR(...) clause in Laravel 5 and Query Builder?

Tags: php, laravel-5, query-builder

The wereYear() function to reproduce `WHERE YEAR(...)` exists, but what about `OR WHERE YEAR(...)`?

In example, how to write this?

```
WHERE YEAR('date_start') = 2015 OR WHERE YEAR('date_start') = 2016

$query->whereYear('date_start', '=', 2015)->????
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've understood how to do that, here the solution.

```
->orWhere(function($nest) use($year) {
    $nest->whereYear('date_start', '=', $year);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
$years = ['2015', '2016'];

$table_records = TableName::whereIn(DB::raw("year(date_start)"), $years)->get();
```